# Block ajax script execution before the previous call succeeded

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a button that executes an ajax function.
Sometimes the server lags so maybe an user presses it more times, thinking the first time it didn't work...
The main ajax function looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "page.php",
        dataType: "html",
        data:"data=data",
        success:  function(){
                ajax2();
                ajax3();
        }
    });
```

Since that ajax function updates db and makes others 2 ajax functions i need to block the button from remake the main ajax func...
Only when ajax2() and ajax3() are finished, the button,  if pressed, must remake the ajax function.
Hope to have explained well my problem!

Comment: you could disable the button on click - and re-enable once all the ajax calls have completed. If the ajax calls were made synchronous then they would, theoretically, fire in turn as the preceding one completes

Comment: It would be easier to provide your with an example, if we knew what it's for. Is it for search? Then you could save the old search query and compare it to the new one. If they match, then don't execute the ajax again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disable the button and then reenable it when the 2 ajax are finished

```
/// the click event
$('yourbutton').prop("disabled",true);
/// show a loading or something....
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "page.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data:"data=data",
    success:  function(){
        var ajax1 = ajax2();
        var ajax2 = ajax3();

        $.when(ajax1,ajax2).done(function(risp1,risp2){
            console.log(risp1,risp2);
            $('yourbutton').prop("disabled",false);
            /// hide the loading
        });
    }
});
```

read [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//before this ajax call disable button
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "page.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: "data=data",
    success: makeAjaxCalls
});

function makeAjaxCalls() {
    var a1 = ajax2();
    var a2 = ajax3();
    $.when(a1, a2).done(function () {
    //enable your button here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unbind the event listener when it's activated the first time :

```
custom_ajax_handler = function(){
    $('#mybutton').unbind('click'); //won't intercept event from now on.

    //here is your ajax call.
    ajax2();
    ajax3();
}

$('#mybutton').click(custom_ajax_handler);
```

Then in ajax3 success rebind it :

```
success : function(){
    $('#mybutton').click(custom_ajax_handler);
}
```

Note that you probably shouldn't make that much ajax calls.
Or at least that doing so won't help your server with its lags.

Comment: Ya but ajax3 can complete before ajax2